# How to make multipleQGIS mapbook pages in 1 pdf?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

Is it possible to export a mapbook in QGIS 2 with multiple pages all in one PDF?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on your problem? What have you tried thus far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I am able to print the map as one page. When I click "Single file output where possible" it still prints one page. I would like to print each square in the grid that I place on the map as a single map, or print a map for a given attribute of a polygon feature class, such as "neighbourhood_name".

Answer (score 2):

Yes - in the print composer, under "Atlas generation" look for the "Single file output where possible" checkbox. Ticking this will generate a single pdf containing all the atlas pages.

Comment: This works in QGIS 2.0 (Dufour), but not in QGIS 2.2 (Valmiera). Is this a bug or is there a different way to do it in 2.2?

Comment: Are you using Atlas -> Export Atlas as PDF to save your atlas? The old way (File->Export as PDF) only saves the current atlas page in 2.2.

Comment: Yes, I have tried both ways of printing. In 2.2, it prints a page for each section that the filter creates, however, each page shows the whole map, not the individual section.

Comment: Ah ok - i misunderstood the issue. Select your map and make sure the "controlled by atlas" checkbox is ticked.

Comment: Yes, that works. Print by Atlas -> Export Atlas and check "controlled by atlas".  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is the answer. As noted above, for QGIS 2.2, check "Single file output where possible", and also Print by Atlas -> Export Atlas and check "controlled by atlas".

First, add a grid to the map with Vector->Research Tools->Vector Grid. Each square in the grid will correspond to a map page, so draw the grid accordingly. The grid makes an attribute named ID, with a starting value of zero. If you want the grids to be labelled starting at one, use the Expression tool in the Label dialog and write:

"ID" + 1

In the Print Composer, use the grid as **Coverage layer**. If you don't want the grid to show, check **Hidden coverage layer**. (I think the label should be "Hide coverage layer".) Select also **Single file export when possible**. For **Filter with**, either manually enter or click the ellipse and use the Expression tool to enter "ID" >-1. This will make map pages of each grid that has an ID > -1 (which is to say, all of the grids). This will produce a different map page in one PDF.

If you want to filter on an attribute in a layer, choose that layer as the coverage layer and then put the attribute in the Filter box that you want. This will create a different map page for each feature that you have selected.